# Finding the Location of the Duplicate for Duplicated Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-cleaning

I know I can find duplicate columns using:

```
df.T.duplicated()
```

what I'd like to know the index that a duplicate column is a duplicate of.  For example, both `C` and `D` are duplicates of a `A` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1,1], [2,0,2,2]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  1  1
1  2  0  2  2
```

I'd like something like:

```
duplicate_index = pd.Series([None, None, 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Comment: what does `[None, None, 'A', 'A']` mean? what if the 1st row has `1  0  1  0` (`C` coincides with `A`, `D` coincides with `B`)?

Comment: Could you add an example of the expected output?

Comment: In reality is this going to be a DataFrame with a lot of columns or a lot of rows to begin with? or both?

Comment: @LucaCappelletti  The example output is at the end. `duplicate_index`

Comment: @ALollz it has 10-20 columns and 200 something rows.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest A,B have no duplicates (A is the first).  C,D are duplicates of A

Comment: I'm happy with an answer like `pd.Series(['A', 'A'], ['C', 'D'])` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if `duplicated` have an option to give information about the first row with the same data. My idea is by using `groupby` and `transform` such as:

```
arr_first = (df.T.reset_index().groupby([col for col in df.T.columns])['index']
                .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]).values)
```

With your example, `arr_first` is then equal to `array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'A'], dtype=object)` and because they have the same order than `df.columns`, to get the expected output, you use `np.where` like:

```
duplicate_index = pd.Series(pd.np.where(arr_first != df.columns, arr_first, None),df.columns)
```

and the result for `duplicate_index` is

```
A    None
B    None
C       A
D       A
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Another more direct way to test if two numeric columns are duplicated with each other is to test the correlation matrix,  which test all pairs of columns.  Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1,1], [2,0,2,2]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# compute the correlation matrix
cm = df.corr()
cm
```

[image]

This shows a matrix of the correlation of all columns to each other column (including itself).  If a column is 1:1 with another column, then the value is 1.0.

To find all columns that are duplicates of A,  then :

```
cm['A']

A    1.0
B    NaN 
C    1.0
D    1.0
```

If you have categorical (string objects) and not numeric,  you could make a cross correlation table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, this may be better in the end as I can get groups as well.

Comment: So I actually ended up using the corr to make a BenT's work more readable.  Thanks.

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear you found a hybrid solution using both answers :)